# Detecting if elements in list are equal, catching non-null lists

Tags: python, list

Is there a preferred way to determine if all elements in a list are equal, **crucially returning `False` for null lists**. I missed the fact that `all(element == my_list[0] for element in my_list)` will return `True` for empty lists. As such, I was intending to use something like:

```
if my_list and all(element == my_list[0] for element in my_list):
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

or

```
if len(set(l)) == 1:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Is there a better solution for checking if all elements are equal but catching null lists.

Comment: the set approach looks nice to me. Though it is worth noting that your `all` approach will shortcircuit, so that's an advantage for it

Comment: I would go with the `len(set(l))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a one-liner, it could be

```
my_list and len(set(my_list)) == 1
```

Or, in a slightly more convoluted way,

```
len(set(my_list or [])) == 1
```

It works if `my_list` is `None`, too.

If you have a lot of code like that, factor this out into a function.

Comment: I think `len(set(my_list)) == 1` should work by itself?

Comment: If `my_list` is `None`, it will not. If `my_list` is an _empty_ list (but not null), it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This version is short and will short-circuit too:

```
test_cases = [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2],
    []
]

for t in test_cases:
    if t and t == t[::-1]:
        print('{} - All elements are equal'.format(t))
    else:
        print('{} - All elements are NOT equal/or null list'.format(t))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 1] - All elements are equal
[1, 1, 2] - All elements are NOT equal/or null list
[] - All elements are NOT equal/or null list
```

Comment: The code should return `False` when the list either contains unequal elements or is empty.

Comment: If I test with `[]` it also returns `True`. Part of the questions was the preferred way to detect empty lists also. i.e. `[]` should return `False` also.

Comment: It's only meant to return True to non-empty lists **and** lists with equal elements.

Comment: So `if t and all([t == t[::-1]])` works, but `all([t == t[::-1]])` alone doesn't work, as demonstrated in the question

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to approach it. I'll share few of what i think.

**1. Your method**

```
bool(my_list) and all([element == my_list[0] for element in my_list])
```

**2. Using `set`**

```
len(set(my_list)) == 1
```

**3. Using `sum` and `len`**

```
sum(my_list)/len(my_list) == my_list[0]
```

**4. Custom function**

```
def list_has_equal_elements(list):
    for element in list:
        if element != list[0]:
            return False
    return True and bool(list) #returns false for empty lists
```

Comment: `bool(len(set([1,2,3]))) == True`; what you meant is `len(set(my_list)) == 1`.

Comment: @9000 `bool(len(set([1,2,3])))` automatically returns True. There's no need to compare afterwards.

Comment: Exactly! It returns True when elements in the list are _not_ equal to each other; it just checks that the list is not empty in a fancy way.